# Disable PAM login but keeping landscape-sysinfo y motd

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam

Running Ubuntu Server, I have no need for PAM login, and thus disabled this service in the `sshd_config` file. However, oddly, there is some login info that is only displayed if you enable PAM logins (but the info is unrelated to PAM). See:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/7949/where-does-the-system-information-information-come-from-on-login

I *do* want to show the landscape info, and I would also like to display other MOTD info (like XX pending updates) upon login. Unfortunately I lost this when disabling PAM. What is the best way to go about this? I tried `PrintMotd yes` in the `sshd_config` but that had no impact.

This is the info that was shown upon login before disabling PAM:

> Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
>   System information as of Wed May 27 02:01:41 EDT 2015
>
>   System load:  0.0               Processes:           101   Usage of
>     /:   6.3% of 42.1GB   Users logged in:     2   Memory usage: 17%
>     IP address for eth0: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX   Swap usage:   0%
>     IP address for eth1: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
>
>   => There are 2 zombie processes.
>
>   Graph this data and manage this system at:
>     https://landscape.canonical.com/
>
> 21 packages can be updated. 14 updates are security updates.

And this is all that is left after disabling PAM:

> Last login: Wed May 27 01:42:36 2015 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That motd output is all generated by running scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/` on every login.  The dynamic motd feature in Ubuntu is governed by [pam_motd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_motd.8.html) (see [update-motd manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/update-motd.5.html) for details), so you need to enable PAM login to see it.

Alternatively, you can call the scripts in the system wide shell profile.  Note that you'd better not use `run-parts` because you have to give up some scripts which are intended to be run as root to store the output in `/var/lib`.

For example you can put the following in `/etc/profile.d/motd.sh`.

```
/etc/update-motd.d/00-header
/etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text
/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo
# /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available # need root
# /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade   # need root
# /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot    # need root
/etc/update-motd.d/98-reboot-required
```

Or you might want to periodically update `/etc/motd` with the output from the scripts using cron.

```
# NOT TESTED!
*/10 * * * * root run-parts /etc/update-motd.d >/etc/motd
```